# How to pair the adjacent values in scala?

Tags: scala

```
 List[String] = List(id:1, count:23331, id:3, count:34123, id:4, count:4021)
```

I have a list of string as above

I want the output to be below

```
 List((1,23331),(3,34123),(4,4021))
```

Scala Code :

```
 scala> val result = res11
 result: List[String] = List(id:1, count:23331, id:3, count:34123, id:4, count:4021)

 scala> result.map(elem => elem.split(":")(1))
 res12: List[String] = List(1, 23331, 3, 34123, 4, 4021)
```

Could someone help me to  get the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result.map(_.split(":")(1)).sliding(2,2).toList.map{case List(a,b) => (a,b)}
```

Comment: result.map(elem => elem.split(":")(1)).grouped(2).toList